# What system is represented by the two-particle interaction $V(r)=\frac{A}{6}r^{-6}+\frac{B}{3}r^{-3}$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential

In an exercise, I was given the following Lagrangian:
$$L=\frac{m}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\dot{q}_j^2-\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}V(q_{j+1}-q_j),$$
where
$$V(r)=\frac{A}{6}r^{-6}+\frac{B}{3}r^{-3}.$$
What kind of physical system could it represent?
Is there any serious study/application for this system?

Comment: [Lennard-Jones potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform do you know of examples involving more than pairs of atoms?

Comment: Hey! @DanielSank, why do you do that? This is not my question. I want to know about physical explanation. Not about how write a Lagrangian. With the title you put in my question you miss my point.

Comment: @ErnestoIglesias The new title asks exactly what you write in your comment. I do not understand your complaint.

Comment: Because any Lagrangian can be writen with a kinetic and two-particle interaction term. And asking that discourage any person who may know the aplication of **this** one to answer that. I'm not saying my title was good but yours miss the point.

Comment: Yes, mine missed the point, but the original one conveyed basically nothing and misused the word "why". Anyway, the most recent one looks quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

van der Waals potential could decay in $1/r^6$, dipole-dipole interaction potential could decay in the form of $1/r^3$. This is probably related to the inter molecular interaction.